# Magento2 : Create multi select category attribute with custom source

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes

Magento2 : Create multi select category attribute with custom source.
Can anyone give me with example?

Comment: Magento version 2.1.0

Answer (score 21):

For a **mult select attribute**, you can need to add  below at your installer:

- **source model:** `[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Custom.php`
- **backend Model** `[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Custom.php`
- **input_renderer for admin html area** `[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Helper\Custom\Options.php`

**Install file[`app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/Setup/InstallData.php`] an code:**

```
<?php
namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory; 
    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        /**
         * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
         */ 
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'multi_custom_attribute',
                      [
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'label' => 'Custom Attribute Description',
                        'input' => 'multiselect',
                        'required' => false,

                        'source' => '[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Custom',
                        'backend' => '[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Custom',
                        'input_renderer' => '[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Helper\Custom\Options',

                        'sort_order' => 100,
                        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'group' => 'General Information',
                        'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                        'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                        'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
            ]
        );


    }
}
```

### Source model:

**location:** `app\code\[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Custom.php`

**code:**

```
<?php
namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Category\Attribute\Source;

class Custom extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{
    /**
     * Catalog config
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config
     */
    protected $_catalogConfig;

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig)
    {
        $this->_catalogConfig = $catalogConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Catalog Config Singleton
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config
     */
    protected function _getCatalogConfig()
    {
        return $this->_catalogConfig;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if ($this->_options === null) {
            $this->_options = [
                                ['label' => __('Label1'), 'value' => 'value1'],
                                ['label' => __('Label2'), 'value' => 'value2'],
                                ['label' => __('Label3'), 'value' => 'value3'],
                                ['label' => __('Label4'), 'value' => 'value4']

                                ];

        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

### backend model:

**location:** `[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Custom.php`

**code:**

```
<?php
namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend;
class Custom extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\AbstractBackend
{
    /**
     * Core store config
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
    {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Validate process
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $object
     * @return bool
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */


    /**
     * Before Attribute Save Process
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $object
     * @return $this
     */
    public function beforeSave($object)
    {
        $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getName();
        if ($attributeCode == 'multi_custom_attribute') {
            $data = $object->getData($attributeCode);
            if (!is_array($data)) {
                $data = [];
            }
            $object->setData($attributeCode, implode(',', $data) ?: null);
        }
        if (!$object->hasData($attributeCode)) {
            $object->setData($attributeCode, null);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * After Load Attribute Process
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $object
     * @return $this
     */
    public function afterLoad($object)
    {
        $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getName();
        if ($attributeCode == 'multi_custom_attribute') {
            $data = $object->getData($attributeCode);
            if ($data) {
                if (!is_array($data)) {
                    $object->setData($attributeCode, explode(',', $data));
                } else {
                    $object->setData($attributeCode, $data);
                }

            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

### input_renderer for admin html area:

**location:** `[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Helper\Custom\Options.php`

**code:**

```
<?php
namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Helper\Custom;

class Options extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Multiselect
{
    /**
     * Returns js code that is used instead of default toggle code for "Use default config" checkbox
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getToggleCode()
    {
        $htmlId = 'use_config_' . $this->getHtmlId();
        return "toggleValueElements(this, this.parentNode.parentNode);" .
            "if (!this.checked) toggleValueElements(\$('{$htmlId}'), \$('{$htmlId}').parentNode);";
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Element HTML fragment
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getElementHtml()
    {
        $elementDisabled = $this->getDisabled() == 'disabled';
        $disabled = false;

        if (!$this->getValue() || $elementDisabled) {
            $this->setData('disabled', 'disabled');
            $disabled = true;
        }

        $html = parent::getElementHtml();
        $htmlId = 'use_config_' . $this->getHtmlId();
        $html .= '<input id="' . $htmlId . '" name="use_config[]" value="' . $this->getId() . '"';
        $html .= $disabled ? ' checked="checked"' : '';

        if ($this->getReadonly() || $elementDisabled) {
            $html .= ' disabled="disabled"';
        }

        $html .= ' onclick="toggleValueElements(this, this.parentNode);" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />';
        $html .= ' <label for="' . $htmlId . '" class="normal">' . __('Use All Available Attributes') . '</label>';
        $html .= '<script>require(["prototype"], function(){toggleValueElements($(\'' .
            $htmlId .
            '\'), $(\'' .
            $htmlId .
            '\').parentNode);});</script>';

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Comment: What code I need to put in [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\view\adminhtml\ui_component\category_form.xml

Comment: i will check and get back to you

Comment: Did you get a solution please? #Amit Bera

Comment: thanks @amit bera you have helped me a lot thank you so much

Comment: Great. It was helpful

Answer (score 6):

This is just an addition to Amits Answer for last step which he has not given.

For admin form you need to create below file.

```
 [VendorName][ModuleName]\view\adminhtml\ui_component\category_form.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="multi_custom_attribute">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">app\code\[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Custom</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Label</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

@Amit you are great.
Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to run the above code. Thanks @Amit for sharing this code and @Ashish for adding missing file but there are three corrections in the paths so as to make the code work. 
Below are the details of the corrections that I have done after which the module worked.

```
First:
In Install file [app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/Setup/InstallData.php] code:
Change:
'backend' => '[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Custom',
To:
'backend' => '[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Custom',


Second:
backend model file location:
Change:
location: [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Custom.php 
To:
location: [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Custom.php

Third Correction is in missing file that @Ashish has shared:
Change:
<item name="options" xsi:type="object">app\code\[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Custom</item>
To:
<item name="options" xsi:type="object">[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Custom</item>
```

Hope it will help to other user's who were facing the same problem. Thanks.