# magento 2 : Multi selected category attribute backend show empty

Tags: magento2, multiselect-attribute

I created module for adding new custom category attribute multi selected type i follow this  link

[Magento2 : Create multi select category attribute with custom source](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134551/magento2-create-multi-select-category-attribute-with-custom-source?answertab=active#tab-top)

In admin it show empty.[image]